# CI looking for Benchmark class in system/Common.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have had no issues on my local test machine, but when moving my project to a webhost (I have php 5.3, webhost is on 5.2.17. That is the only difference in the setup) I encounter this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'CI_Benchmark' not found in /home/veloxtnt/public_html/system/core/Common.php on line 174
```

I've never run into it before and I can't find what is actually looking for the benchmarking class in `common.php`... I'm not even using the benchmarking class, and the only occurrence of `CI_Benchmark` is in `system/benchmark.php`.

I am quite stumped.

Comment: In "common" is where the class is loaded (`$_class = new $_name`), and afaik that class is loaded by default. Did you try to re-upload the system files? is the class there?

Comment: Thanks Damien, I don't know how or why, but I had uploaded the files twice and still the error; deleted everything and reuploaded fresh for a third time and working now.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ZenSavona: Please add your solution as an answer below and accept it so that your question is marked as answered. This will help to make this site work. Thank you!

Comment: As a side point - please move your system folder out of your public_html folder to increase security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had uploaded the files twice and still the error; deleted everything and reuploaded fresh for a third time and working now. Thanks for the help.